# How can I create a classifier using the feature map of a CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I intend to make a classifier using the feature map obtained from a CNN. Can someone suggest how I can do this?

Would it work if I first train the CNN using +ve and -ve samples (and hence obtain the weights), and then every time I need to classify an image, I apply the conv and pooling layers to obtain the feature map? The problem I find in this, is that the image I want to classify, may not have a similar feature map, and hence I wouldn't be able to find the distance correctly. As the order of the features may by different in the layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same CNN for classification if you used (for example) the cross entropy loss-(also known as softmax with loss). In this case, you should take the argmax of your last layer (the node with the highest score), and that would be the class given by the network. However, all the architectures used in machine learning would expect at testing time an input similar to those used during training.